# Where to find information on ILS categories at European airports?

Tags: ils, aeronautical-information

I have a list of airports in Europe and I need to find up-to-date information about ILS categories (I, II, IIIa, IIIb or IIIc) at these airports. Does anyone know where I could find such data efficiently?

Comment: There is no single repository, if this is what you are after. Like for the US, each country has its AIS which publishes an AIP. The information is within individual airport information in the AIP. E.g. the [AIP for France](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/documents/htmlshow?f=dvd/eAIP_02_MAR_2017/FRANCE/home.html), and an [ILS Cat I-II-III](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/dvd/eAIP_02_FEB_2017/FRANCE/AIRAC-2017-02-02/html/eAIP/Cartes/IAC/LFPG/AD%202%20LFPG%20IAC%20RWY08R%20FNA%20-ILS%20CAT123%20LOC.pdf) approach for De Gaulle 08R.

Comment: Try here: http://www.aviationwap.com/SearchForm.php

Answer (score 2):

The information you are after is, unfortunately, rather distributed.

Eurocontrol maintains a useful list of websites ordered by state, found here:

[European AIS](http://www.eurocontrol.int/articles/ais-online)

Or by registering for an **EAD Basic** account you can access the European AIS Database in a more centralised and user friendly way, found here:

[European AIS Database](https://www.ead.eurocontrol.int/eadcms/eadsite/index.php.html)